# Caret span floated right on button not aligned vertically bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason, floating the caret in the second span to the right causes it to not be centered vertically in the dropdown button, how can I fix this?

http://www.bootply.com/nYoCSGGsbx

Notice the caret on the right is awkwardly placed higher than it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="width: 100%" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="pull-left">Source</span>
  <span class="pull-right"><span class="caret"></span></span>
</button>
```

Bootply : http://www.bootply.com/rPp3iqob5d

Comment: Works perfectly